# Gui jframe works differently from netbeans

Tags: java, swing

I have this problem and I thought that images might work better than explaining it. This Java program is built in net beans and when I run it in netbeans, it works fine. But when I run it from the folder clicking the Java tea cup only have of it works.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
try {
    String key = Password.getText();

    if (key.length() < 8 || key.length() > 8 || !key.equals("Password")) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a valid key");

    } else {

        DESKeySpec dks = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes());
        SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey desKey = skf.generateSecret(dks);

        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        Code.dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        Code.dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey, paramSpec);

        Code.decrypt(new FileInputStream("encrypted.txt"),
                new FileOutputStream("cleartext-reversed.txt"));

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "cleartext-reversed.txt"));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            String decrypted = sb.toString();
            DisplayArea2.setText(decrypted);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                    null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class.getName()).log(
                        Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

    }

} catch (InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException
        | InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchPaddingException
        | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
            ex);
}
```

Comment: Sorry off topic, but isn't that coffe?

Comment: @eldo No, its the famous [Java Tea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_coffee) :P.

Comment: Is your encrypted.txt (the one you use in FileInputStream) in the same directory as the packaged jar?

Comment: Where is the information form the logger going?

Comment: Please, attach a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) that we can use to reproduce the issue.

Comment: If your'e using any external libraries, make sure to move them in the src folder and add them from there

Comment: Have you tried running it from the command line to have a look at the stacktrace?